# Intro to Super Yang Mills theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, yang-mills

I'm looking to start learning [Super Yang Mills theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super+Yang-Mills+theory). Currently I have studied Peskin and Schroeder up to the Renormalization Group, but don't know supersymmetry yet. I know some Conformal Field Theory. Looking for a text book or pedagogical notes.

Comment: I think [D'hoker and Freedman](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253) is the standard pedagogical reference for SYM.